# Z-index on IE7/IE8

Tags: z-index

So here the picture of what I'm trying to do:

http://imageshack.us/content_round.php?page=done&l=img14/1023/62507155.jpg

FF diplay is OK, IE8 - don't know ie on 1 PC is OK, checking from another is not OK, IE7 is not OK.

I've got a div with positioning relative and a backgroung picture which is transparent and overlays div 2. Div 2 is positioned absolute and sticked to the bottom of div1 with z-index: -1.

How can I make it look the same on all browsers (IE7/8 in particular)? I've read about putting higger z-index on parent div and lower on nested div but it just makes div2 to be on top on all browsers.

here is the code:

```
#div1 { 
 position: relative;
 height: 900px;
 width: 850px;
 float: left;
 background: url(img/background-left.png) no-repeat;

}
#div2 {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 850px;
    height: 420px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: none;
    z-index: -1;
}
<div id="div1">
    <div id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

If I remove position relative from div1 then its background is always on top of div2 like I want it, but then without position relative I cannot stick div 2 to the bottom of div1.

Comment: Have you tried adding z-index: 0; to div1?

Comment: I did - still puts div 2 on top. Or maybe there is different way to stick div2 to the bottom of div1?

Comment: not very sure, but maybe IE somehow increases the z's after putting the elements to their place? Have you tried putting larger values like 50 just to be sure?

Comment: yes I did try with different values ranging from -1 to 3000

Comment: This does not work because you need div1 and div2 to be at the same level. They need to be sibling in order for the z-index to work. Put div2 outside div1 and it should work.